# Real Analysis, Existence of a Limit Boundedly:$|\int_0^b\frac{sin(ax)}{x}dx | \le c$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis

I need to show that there exists a $c$ such that $|\int_0^b\frac{sin(ax)}{x}dx | \le c$, where $a$ is any real number, and $b$ is any real number greater than 0. Also I need to show that the smallest $c$ possible is $c=\int_0^\pi\frac{sinx}{x}dx$. I know that $\int_0^\infty \frac{sin(ax)}{x}dx = sig(a)\frac{\pi}{2}$ where $sig(a)$ literally just means positive one or negative one, depending on the sign of $a$. I think the fourier tranform of the characteristic function on the interval $(0,a)$ is $\frac{sin(ax)}{x}$. After that, I am unsure about how to proceed. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, a change of variables gives
$$ I(a,b) := \int_0^b \frac{\sin(ax)}{x} dx = \int_0^{ab} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} dx. $$
Since the integrand is an even function, we may assume that $ab>0$, hence both $a$ and $b$ are positive. It is easy to see that the integral is in fact positive for all $ab$. Note that the maximum value this integral depends only on the produxt $ab>0$. Consider then the function $f(\alpha) = \int_0^\alpha \sin(x)/x dx$. Differentiating this, we get
$$  f'(\alpha) = \frac{\sin(\alpha)}{\alpha}, $$
which is zero if and only if $\alpha = n\pi$ with $n > 0$ being an integer. Note that $f'(\alpha)$ is alternating in sign between each interval $[(n-1)\pi,n\pi]$, showing that for all integers $N\geq 0$
$$ f(N\pi) = \sum_{n=1}^{N} i_n , \quad i_n := \int_{(n-1)\pi}^{n\pi} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} dx. $$
Now, $i_n$ is an alternating sequence. The sum of an alternating sequence where the first element is positive, is bounded by this element. It follows that $f(N\pi) \leq i_1$.

Comment: Ahh, perfect. This is concise and really good, thank you!

Comment: Wow. Very nice work. I see this much better from a geometric standpoint now.